# find neighbours in np array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 arrays with grid pixel coordinates.

```
[402, 401, 356, 355, 356, 355, 356, 386, 354, 355, 356, 386, 354, 355, 386, 354, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 287, 288, 290, 291, 292, 293, 292, 293, 294, 295, 293, 294, 295, 296, 294, 295, 296, 146, 145, 146, 167, 168, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 160, 161, 162, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 162, 163, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 163, 167, 168, 169, 170, 168, 169, 169, 170, 170, 310, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 311, 312, 313, 314, 274, 275, 275, 274, 275, 274, 275, 273, 274, 275, 274, 275, 274, 272, 273, 272, 273, 272, 273, 272, 273, 272, 273, 271, 272, 271]
[242, 243, 257, 258, 258, 259, 259, 259, 260, 260, 260, 260, 261, 261, 261, 262, 284, 284, 284, 284, 284, 284, 285, 285, 285, 285, 285, 285, 286, 286, 286, 286, 287, 287, 287, 287, 288, 288, 288, 326, 327, 327, 337, 337, 338, 338, 338, 338, 338, 338, 338, 338, 338, 339, 339, 339, 339, 339, 339, 339, 339, 339, 340, 340, 340, 340, 340, 340, 340, 341, 341, 341, 341, 341, 342, 342, 343, 343, 344, 382, 383, 383, 383, 383, 383, 383, 383, 383, 384, 384, 384, 384, 384, 384, 384, 385, 385, 385, 385, 385, 385, 386, 386, 386, 386, 386, 386, 387, 387, 387, 387, 416, 416, 417, 418, 418, 419, 419, 420, 420, 420, 421, 423, 427, 428, 428, 429, 429, 430, 430, 431, 431, 432, 432, 433, 433, 434]
```

There are about 8 spots in the data where the numers connect eachother. The main issue is, how to find those spots. We want to create an array for every spot with the numbers in it. I think this is a simple problem, but still no luck to find out how to program this.

I have tried something with while and for loops but ended up with nothing. What would be the best way to do this ?

Comment: What are those `8 spots` ? whats your expected output?

Comment: output should be in this case, 8 arrays with the pixel coordinates from the starting x and y array

Comment: I would reshape it so you had n x 2 i.e. each xy location then use a distance calculation and np.with distance < threshold. I will try and do you an actual example with your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not sure why it's coming up with the extra spots but they look to match in your lists. I get 175 spots! (certainly 2-4,   3-4,   3-5,   4-6,   5-6 look to match in your lists). Maybe I'm using a different criterion. Here's the code for you to hack as you want:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[402, 401, 356, 355, 356, 355, 356, 386, 354, 355, 356, 386, 354, 355, 386, 354, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 287, 288, 290, 291, 292, 293, 292, 293, 294, 295, 293, 294, 295, 296, 294, 295, 296, 146, 145, 146, 167, 168, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 160, 161, 162, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 162, 163, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 163, 167, 168, 169, 170, 168, 169, 169, 170, 170, 310, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 311, 312, 313, 314, 274, 275, 275, 274, 275, 274, 275, 273, 274, 275, 274, 275, 274, 272, 273, 272, 273, 272, 273, 272, 273, 272, 273, 271, 272, 271],
              [242, 243, 257, 258, 258, 259, 259, 259, 260, 260, 260, 260, 261, 261, 261, 262, 284, 284, 284, 284, 284, 284, 285, 285, 285, 285, 285, 285, 286, 286, 286, 286, 287, 287, 287, 287, 288, 288, 288, 326, 327, 327, 337, 337, 338, 338, 338, 338, 338, 338, 338, 338, 338, 339, 339, 339, 339, 339, 339, 339, 339, 339, 340, 340, 340, 340, 340, 340, 340, 341, 341, 341, 341, 341, 342, 342, 343, 343, 344, 382, 383, 383, 383, 383, 383, 383, 383, 383, 384, 384, 384, 384, 384, 384, 384, 385, 385, 385, 385, 385, 385, 386, 386, 386, 386, 386, 386, 387, 387, 387, 387, 416, 416, 417, 418, 418, 419, 419, 420, 420, 420, 421, 423, 427, 428, 428, 429, 429, 430, 430, 431, 431, 432, 432, 433, 433, 434]])
a = a.T
b = np.where(
      (abs(np.subtract.outer(a[:,0], a[:,0])) <= 1.0) &
      (abs(np.subtract.outer(a[:,1], a[:,1])) <= 1.0))
non_dup = np.where(b[0] < b[1]) # remove double count and 'self' overlaps
b = (b[0][non_dup], b[1][non_dup]) # remake slimmed down index


def find_group(group, start):
  st_ix = np.where(b[0] == start)
  for i in st_ix[0]:
    dest = b[1][i]
    group.add(start)
    group.add(dest) # is this needed?
    find_group(group, dest)

group_list = []

for i in b[0]: # NB this part is slow - it would be better to eliminate entries already dealt with - you can figure that out!
  gp = set()
  find_group(gp, i)
  add_group = True
  for old_gp in group_list:
    if len(gp.intersection(old_gp)) > 0: # hopefully this has fixed it
      old_gp = old_gp.union(gp)
      add_group = False
      break
  if add_group:
    group_list.append(gp)


xy_list = []

for gp in group_list:
  xy_list.append(np.array([a[i] for i in gp]))

print(xy_list)
```

EDIT modified as above to create a list of numpy arrays of contiguous pixels as discussed in comments. Results in this

```
[array([[402, 242],
   [401, 243]]),
array([[356, 257],
   [355, 258],
   [356, 258],
   [355, 259],
   [356, 259],
   [354, 260],
   [355, 260],
   [356, 260],
   [354, 261],
   [355, 261],
   [354, 262]]),
array([[386, 260],
   [386, 261],
   [386, 259]]),
array([[287, 284],
   [288, 284],
   [289, 284],
   [290, 284],
   [291, 284],
   [292, 284],
   [287, 285],
   [288, 285],
   [290, 285],
   [291, 285],
   [292, 285],
   [293, 285],
   [292, 286],
   [293, 286],
   [294, 286],
   [295, 286],
   [293, 287],
   [294, 287],
   [295, 287],
   [296, 287],
   [294, 288],
   [295, 288],
   [296, 288]]),
array([[145, 327],
   [146, 327],
   [146, 326]]),
array([[167, 337],
   [168, 337],
   [166, 338],
   [167, 338],
   [168, 338],
   [169, 338],
   [170, 338],
   [165, 339],
   [166, 339],
   [167, 339],
   [168, 339],
   [169, 339],
   [170, 339],
   [166, 340],
   [167, 340],
   [168, 340],
   [169, 340],
   [170, 340],
   [167, 341],
   [168, 341],
   [169, 341],
   [170, 341],
   [168, 342],
   [169, 342],
   [169, 343],
   [170, 343],
   [170, 344]]),
array([[163, 341],
   [160, 339],
   [161, 339],
   [162, 339],
   [162, 340],
   [163, 340]]),
array([[310, 382],
   [310, 383],
   [311, 383],
   [312, 383],
   [313, 383],
   [314, 383],
   [315, 383],
   [316, 383],
   [317, 383],
   [311, 384],
   [312, 384],
   [313, 384],
   [314, 384],
   [315, 384],
   [316, 384],
   [317, 384],
   [311, 385],
   [312, 385],
   [313, 385],
   [314, 385],
   [315, 385],
   [316, 385],
   [311, 386],
   [312, 386],
   [313, 386],
   [314, 386],
   [315, 386],
   [316, 386],
   [311, 387],
   [312, 387],
   [313, 387],
   [314, 387]]),
array([[274, 416],
   [275, 416],
   [275, 417],
   [274, 418],
   [275, 418],
   [274, 419],
   [275, 419],
   [273, 420],
   [274, 420],
   [275, 420],
   [274, 421]]),
array([[272, 430],
   [273, 430],
   [272, 431],
   [273, 431],
   [272, 432],
   [273, 432],
   [271, 433],
   [272, 433],
   [271, 434],
   [274, 427],
   [273, 428],
   [272, 429],
   [273, 429]])]
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are 137 points in the array, and in this array there should be 8 spots with the points, so i dont think i can use your code. i dont understand your script.

Comment: maybe give a little more explanation of what you want. My code takes your first array as x coord, second array as y coord. Is that right for a start? It then looks at the distance between each of the 137 points and all the other 137 points (yes distance from itself!) and compares that with a threshold (I used <= 1) it then discards duplicates and self-self. There are obviously more than 137 inter point distances. My calculation shows there are 175 where the distance == 1. Would you count point 2(356,257)-4(356,258) in your 8ish?

Comment: Sorry paddyg, the x and y coordinates are points to plot on a 2d grid. its hard to explain but the grid shape is 500*500 and the combination of array (x) and array(y) is the coordinate in the grid. There are a couple of groups with a lot of coordinates that are close to each other (1pixel neighbours) and i want to group these in new arrays.

Comment: so are the points 0(402,242) 1(401,234) 2(356,257) 3(355,258) 4(356,258)? On that basis would you say 1 pixel distance were 2-4 and 3-4?

Comment: Yes, thats correct! so these should be in the same array as they are connecting neighbours from each other

Comment: OK, so what about 0-1 2-3 2-4 3-4 they are diagonally next to each other?

Comment: Yes, thats also good, sorry forgot to mention

Comment: Right. There are 317 pairs like that in your list. It should be possible to clear out chaining adjacent points with a little recursive function, I will post something up for you in a while.

Comment: thanks, to clearify, i don't need the number of pairs or something, i need the 137 array elements to be grouped as they are connected. In the sample data array i have posted in the first post, there are about 8 groups, but with different counts and with spaces between. http://i62.tinypic.com/25i954m.png this is an sample image, you see some sort of 8 clusters, this is the output from the sample data. So the 2 sample arrays with x and y should be divided in 8 arrays containing the points of each cluster.

Comment: @Olivier I posted an edit though I can see it's not quite right. Probably need to check out the recursive function which is not picking up groups having the same destination pixel. Will think what's needed (possibly use set intersection)

Comment: Thanks for the update! Thats looking nice, im going to try this out!

Comment: Is it easy to add one more array for input, containing data for the x and y points ?

Comment: well yes... Depending! In my example above a.shape could be (3,137) instead of (2,137) with the third value being 'data'. The final result would then be 3 rather than 2 in its last dimension. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Ehm, where should i do that exactly ?

Comment: so where it has a = np.array([[402, 401...],[242, 243...],[666999, 969696,...]) and the extra data will be included in the output

Comment: well, i have tried that, but i get this error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Sorry problem with my array, works now thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive way of doing it:

```
from itertools import product

def neighbours(xs,ys):
  xys = list(zip(xs,ys))
  for x,y in product(range(max(xs)),range(max(ys))):
    if (x,y) in xys:
      if (x+1,y) in xys:
        yield [(x,y),(x+1,y)]
      if (x,y+1) in xys:
        yield [(x,y),(x,y+1)]
```

For your input, this generates something of the form `[[(287, 287), (288, 287)], [(287, 287), (287, 288)], [(288, 288), (289, 288)], [(386, 386), (386, 387)], ...]`.

To get a list of 8 tuples as output, change the `yield [...]` statements into separate `yield` statements for each list item.

Comment: Thanks, as i use data that changes every hour we should calculate the number of tuples and make an array with the containing x and y in it!

Comment: @Marein, is this what you meant by the numbers connecting with each other? The code seems to be looking at a diagonal as x and y will obviously always be the same value from a zip(range(),range())

Comment: Right, my code didn't make much sense. Fixed.